# getSymbols (in R quantmod package) not working for FRED data

Tags: r, quantmod

the `getSymbols` command in R's quantmod package is no longer working for FRED data (i.e., for St. Louis Fed data base via: fred.stlouisfed.org). For example, using the quantmod help menu in R offers this example, which no longer works:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('CPIAUCNS',src='FRED')
```

Running this command produces this error:

```
Error: Failed to download file. Error message:
cannot open URL 
'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CPIAUCNS/downloaddata/CPIAUCNS.csv'
If this is related to https, possible solutions are:
1. Explicitly pass method= via the getSymbols call (or via setDefaults)
2. Install downloader, which may be able to automagically determine a method
3. Set the download.file.method global option
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, quiet, mode, cacheOK, extra) :
  cannot open URL 
'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CPIAUCNS/downloaddata/CPIAUCNS.csv': 
HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

Apparently the web page address for FRED tickers has been changed by the St Louis Fed and it's not obvious (at least to me) what the new address is. You can still download data manually into an Excel file. But the `getSymbols` for FRED is broken. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Update: A fix in progress can be found here: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/209

Comment: In the last 5 minutes, the links have started working again on FRED.

Comment: Yes, I've found that as well. I'm guessing that the St Louis Fed changed the relevant link back to the previous URL. In any case, all seems well at the moment for the getSymbols as it relates to FRED data.